# A basic question about installing ubuntu on a partitioned hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I have an intel nuc computer with one hard drive and Windows 7 installed on it (some constrains make higher windows versions not suitable for my work). I have recently created a new partition and installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on it. 
I planned on setting boot priorities from setup and didn't think of the fact that setup does not recognize splitted parts of the same hard drive.
Now I can only start my computer with Ubuntu. I have some programs installed on my Windows 7 OS which need to work with.

I assume that if I could format the partition on which the Ubuntu is installed, the computer, when uploading, will recognize the Windows installation (which is located in a separate partition and was not touched)

I need to format the partition on which the Ubuntu is located in, assuming that with no Ubuntu, the computer will startup from windows (am I right?).
I tried to do that uploading the computer from the image usb with the Ubuntu installation. I can format (i.e.erase) partitions there. The problem is, that if I format through the Ubuntu installation, I have to complete installation process and, again, can't upload windows.
If I quit the installation right after formatting, the format is canceled and,again, I am left with Ubuntu only without the windows.

> **So my question is:**
>   How do I format the Ubuntu partition without installing Ubuntu again and without erasing the windows 7 installation?
>   Is there a way to format certain partitions on the computer without running an operation system that will block the windows installation?

Thanks a lot for any help & suggestions

Comment: Formating your Ubuntu partition will break your computer. You have to correctly set up your boot loader, most likely `grub` or `grub2`. Your computer will not fall back to Windows if you remove Linux. Don't try. Instead, set up your bootloader correctly.

Comment: You can update grub to boot Windows. `sudo update-grub`. If that does not find Windows then you have other Windows issues or did not install Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows UEFI or BIOS. Both must be same. And you normally need a Windows repair disk to reinstall the Windows boot loader to MBR (if BIOS) or a few Windows 7 that are UEFI may need full set of Windows repairs.